# Would Narcan (Naloxone) counteract the effects of an Epidural?

Tags: internal-consistency, medical

A heroine in the fourth of my book series must get on her feet suddenly after delivery.  Would Naloxone work on an epidural as well as it works on other narcotics?

Comment: This looks off-topic here. I'm not sure which site would be the best fit for this, but the question doesn't appear to be about worldbuilding.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. This is pretty short, could you flesh it out a bit? For example how much time passes? And a tip for the future: on SE it is recommended to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to allow users from different timezones to have a look at your question and the answers. Some people might be discouraged from answering a question with an accepted answer. Have fun!

Comment: Also, Naloxone and *heroins* do not mix well.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. It depends on what was used for the epidural; for example the fentanyl drug family are μ-type opioids and, as such, would be negated by naloxone.

On the other hand, the more commonly used bupivicaine blocks nerve cell sodium channels, and is not inhibited by naloxone at all.

Answer (score 1):

Only for the potion of administered drugs that fall under the opioid family, the others such as Lidocaine would remain unaffected.

Comment: Thank you.  It is made up almost entirely of non narcotics as I look deeper.  Will have to simply have her refuse the and take Iv narcotics as she knows she needs to be up.